# python dicttoxml same key multiple times

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7

I am trying to do xml that looks like:

```
<xml....
<key1>aaa </key1>
<key1>bbb</key1>
<key1>ccc</key1>
</xml>
```

using python dicttoxml lib

tried:

```
quest_dict = [{'key1': 'aaa'}, {'key1': 'bbb'}, {'key1': 'ccc'}]
request_xml = dicttoxml.dicttoxml(request_dict, attr_type=False, root=False)
```

but got bad xml not as excepted. 
Thanks for help!

Comment: Does your output look different than expected or do you get an error message?

Answer (score 5):

You can create a dictionary with a repeating key by wrapping the keys with a dummy class and then use dicttoxml on that dictionary. Use [collections.OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) if the order matters:

```
from dicttoxml import dicttoxml
from collections import OrderedDict

class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = name

    def __str__(self):
        return self._name

quest_dict = OrderedDict([(Node('key1'), 'aaa'), (Node('key1'), 'bbb'), (Node('key1'), 'ccc')])
request_xml = dicttoxml(quest_dict, attr_type=False, root=False)
print(request_xml)
```

This gives your desired output:

```
b'<key1>aaa</key1><key1>bbb</key1><key1>ccc</key1>'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the xml you expect using the *custom_root* and *item_func* arguments to the [dicttoxml](https://pypi.org/project/dicttoxml/) method:

```
import dicttoxml

request_dict = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
item_name = lambda x: 'key1'
request_xml = dicttoxml.dicttoxml(request_dict, attr_type=False, custom_root='xml', item_func=item_name)

print(request_xml.decode('utf-8'))
```

Output:

```
<xml><key1>aaa</key1><key1>bbb</key1><key1>ccc</key1></xml>
```

An extension to this example is solving the case of multiple repeating keys in a single xml, like defined by `<xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">`
which I could neither achieve using *OrderedDict* from Dave's answer. The closest result is using a the *item_func* lambda that names the items in the name of the parent:

```
import dicttoxml

xml_dict = {}
xml_dict['key1'] = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
xml_dict['another-key'] = ['a','b','c']

item_name = lambda x: x
request_xml = dicttoxml.dicttoxml(xml_dict, attr_type=False, custom_root='xml', item_func=item_name)

print(request_xml.decode('utf-8'))
```

But then we you'll have to remove the parents from the result:

```
<xml>
    <key1>
        <key1>aaa</key1>
        ...
```

Clean up can be applied (explicit):

```
xml_str = request_xml.decode("utf-8", "strict")
xml_str = xml_str.replace('<key1><key1>', '<key1>').replace('</key1></key1>', '</key1>')
xml_str = xml_str.replace('<another-key><another-key>', '<another-key>').replace('</another-key></another-key>', '</another-key>')
print(xml_str)
```

Result:

```
<xml>
    <key1>aaa</key1>
    ...
    <another-key>a</another-key>
    ...
</xml>
```

Answer (score 0):

In version 1.7.16 of dicttoxml the following snippet runs with no problems:

```py
request_dict = [{'key1': 'aaa'}, {'key1': 'bbb'}, {'key1': 'ccc'}]
request_xml = dicttoxml(request_dict, attr_type=False)
```

The resulting xml of this dict will be

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<root>
    <item>
        <key1>aaa</key1>
    </item>
    <item>
        <key1>bbb</key1>
    </item>
    <item>
        <key1>ccc</key1>
    </item>
</root>
```