# Replace child attribute to parent attibute

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am able to create xml with duplicate key and follow suggested answer

[python dicttoxml same key multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37932344/python-dicttoxml-same-key-multiple-times)

But it hit badly performance issue when i user custom class fore more than 1 million record.

```
class Node():
    """
    creating class to convert dictionary to xml
    Returns:
        Node : object which contain child tag name
    """
    __slots__ = ['_name']
    
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = name

    def __str__(self):
        return self._name

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self._name)
```

I have tried to update node class(above) but did not get efficient time improvement.

Later I move to follow link which suggest to use default which is really faster and data process in less than 5 min

[Why is dictionary lookup in Python always slower when using user defined objects as keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52127854/why-is-dictionary-lookup-in-python-always-slower-when-using-user-defined-objects)

```
{ 'data' : { 'check' : {'error' : ['data1', 'data2'] } } }
 <data>
   <check>
    <error>
        <item> data1 </item>
        <item> data2 </item>    
    </error>
   </check>
 </data>
```

But I am looking xml following way. is there anyway to get following xml.

```
<data>
   <check>
    <error> data1 </error>
    <error> data2 </error>
   </check>
 </data>
```

Node class dict

```
{'data' : {Node('check') : { Node('error') : "data1", Node('error') : "data2" } } }


with open(fpath, "w") as fxml:
            vio_xml_data = dicttoxml(vio_data)
            dom = parseString(vio_xml_data)
            fxml.writelines(dom.toprettyxml())
```

Comment: You could try the second option in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/11141570/7868736

Comment: What are you doing with these classes? I have no idea what you're asking without specific code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This returns exactly what your looking for

```
from dict2xml import dict2xml

data = {'data':
            {'check':
                 {'error': ["data1", "data2"]}
             }
        }

xml = dict2xml(data)
print(xml)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
<data>
  <check>
    <error>data1</error>
    <error>data2</error>
  </check>
</data>
```

NOTE: I'm not using your node class here. Just make sure the "error" key in the dict is a list of values.

Comment: Thanks But i am getting like this. <root>
 <data type="dict">
  <check type="dict">
   <error type="list">
    <item type="str">data1 </item>
    <item type="str">data2</item>
   </error>

Comment: @user765443 from the output it looks like you're using `dicttoxml`. In my answer im using `dict2xml`. This ones does not let you add attributes to tags, and format the xml output too much, but gives you exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: ya just tested it, your using `dicttoxml`, if you can use `dict2xml` it will solve this problem.

Comment: Thx Anu.. small utility but help me to fix large issue thx